# How to resolve error to get SSL certificate using Letsencrypt certbot?

Tags: server, dns, nginx, letsencrypt

Using `certbot` from Let'sEncrypt, I couldn't manage to create secure access for `tleis.nl`, but if I copy the site into `chess.tleis.nl`, then secure access is done without problems. But I still cannot get secure access for the base domain `tleis.nl`.

I have the following:

- OS: Ubuntu server 18.04
- Nginx: 1.15.5

My website files are in:

```
/var/www/tleis.nl
```

In the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/tleis.nl`:

```
server {
  root /var/www/tleis.nl; 
  index index.html index.htm; 
  server_name tleis.nl www.tleis.nl; 
  location / { 
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Now if I do:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d tleis.nl
```

Then I am getting a message that `tleis.nl is unauthorized`:

```
The following errors were reported by the server:
Domain: tleis.nl
Type: unauthorized
```

If I duplicate this site into `chess.tleis.nl` for example:

```
sudo cp -r /var/www/tleis.nl /var/www/chess.tleis.nl
sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/tleis.nl /etc/nginx/sites-available/chess.tleis.nl
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/chess.tleis.nl /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chess.tleis.nl
sudo nginx -t
udo certbot --nginx -d chess.tleis.nl
```

Then I change the content of chess.tleis.nl to point to the new site. For example the 'root' is set to /var/www/chess.tleis.nl; and server_name chess.tleis.nl;

Running the command `sudo certbot --nginx -d chess.tleis.nl' works perfectly and as a result`https://chess.tleis.nl` is accessible now!

chess.tleis.nl is just an example to illustrate that I could get a certificate for any sub-domain (I also duplicated it to many other sub-domains and generated separate certificates for each without problems, for example: python.tleis.nl and ds.tleis.nl). But still couldn't manage to get the certificate for the root 'tleis.nl'.

Any hints where should I look next?

Comment: If you look at your certificate details (from a Web browser), you will see that it is for `chess.tleis.nl`, and not for `tleis.nl` or anything else. You may need another certificate or use a "wildcard certificate".

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am using chess.tleis.nl as an example. I have as well duplicated the root website 'tleis.nl' into many others that start with anything.tleis.nl. For example python.tleis.nl or ds.tleis.nl. I could get the certificate with no problems. I still cannot do it for tleis.nl (the root domain)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a faulty AAAA record.

the base domain `tleis.nl` had both an A and AAAA record. The AAAA record was pointing to a wrong ip v.6 address.

'*.tleis.nl' had only an A record.

Apparently letsencrypt was checking all the available records.